# Find the equation of the diameter of the circle having equation $x^2+y^2-6x+2y-8=0$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

Find the equation of the diameter of the circle having equation $x^2+y^2-6x+2y-8=0$.

My Work:
$$x^2+y^2-6x+2y-8=0$$
Comparing the above equation with $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$, we get:
$$g=-3$$,
$$f=1$$
Now, 
$$\textrm {centre}=(-g,-f)$$
$$=(3,-1)$$

Comment: A diameter is a number... Are you sure you want to get the equation into the standard form $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$ ?

Comment: @VivekKaushik, I want the equation of the diameter.

Comment: You want the **value** of the diameter...

Comment: We surely can find the value of the diameter. For finding the equation, we need atleast one more information: either the slope or a point through which it passes.

Comment: When you say you want an equation for the diameter, are you looking for the equation of a line segment? That is impossible. If you want the equation of the line that contains a diameter, that's any line that goes through the center of the circle. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "Completing the Square".

Solving your system $x^{2}+y^{2}−6x+2y−8=0$, you can add and substract some numbers to get the classical circle equation $(x-h)^{2}+(y-k)^{2}=r^{2}$.

Well, you can check that your problem is equivalent to $$(x-3)^2+(y+1)^2=18$$ So your radius is $\sqrt{18}=3\sqrt{2}$, and your center $(3,-1)$

I dont know what you mean about "the equation of the diamater" but if you have a point $(a,b)$ the equation that passes through the point and the diamenter is:
$$y=\frac{b-3}{a+1}(x-a)+b$$

Answer (score 1):

Supposed the equation describes a surface with height function:

$$g(x,y) = x^2+y^2-6x+2y-8 $$

The circle is the intersection $g(x,y)=0$

To find the center of the circle. The way I do it is by solving the following 2×2 system $$\left. \begin{align} \frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}=0 \\\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}=0  \end{align} \right\} \begin{aligned} x & = 3 \\ y & =-1 \end{aligned}$$

To find a line through the center $(3,-1)$ find the coefficients that solve $a x + b y + c =0$ with the above values. If you realize that $(a,b)$ is a vector perpendicular to the line then you can write $(a,b)=(-\sin \varphi,\cos \varphi)$ with $\varphi$ the angle of the line from the horizontal.

Now we solve $(-\sin \varphi) (3) + (\cos \varphi) (-1) + c = 0$ for $c=\cos\varphi+3 \sin\varphi$. So the equation of the line through the center of the circle is

$$ (-\sin\varphi) x + (\cos\varphi) y + (\cos\varphi+3 \sin\varphi) =0 $$

This can be simplified as

$$\boxed{ -(x-3) \sin\varphi + (y+1) \cos\varphi =0 }$$

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the center of that circle is: $(3,-1)$.

Now as there no other particular point is specified on this circle we can draw infinite number of diameters of that circle. Therefore there can be infinite number of straight line equations.

As for example the equation of the diameter of this circle which passes through the origin can be given by:
$$\dfrac{y+1}{x-3}=\dfrac{-1-0}{3-0}\\
\implies x+3y=0$$

Answer (score -1):

Complete the square

$$x^2 + y^2 -6x + 2y -8 = 0$$
$$x^2-6x + 9 - 9 +y^2+2y + 1-1-8= 0$$
$$(x-3)^2+(y+1)^2 = 18$$

Therefore, $18 = r^2,$ and diameter $= 6\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I think you misread tje question. I want the equation of the diameter, not the VALUE.

Comment: The diameter is a value, not an equation.

Comment: @Kaynex, If I am not mistaken, Diameter is a straight line passing through the centre. Since its a straight line, it has an equation.

Comment: @Aryabhatta please explain (or with an example) what would _an equation_ be for the diameter?

Comment: @Aryabhatta there are infinite lines passing through the center. If this is what you want I advice to edit the question to indicate you want the equation of a line through a point (the center).

Comment: @ja72, If I knew the example to explain, I would not ask this question here.

Comment: Okay. It's unconventional, but sure. A straight line that passes through the center of the circle is given by $y = m(x - 3) - 1$, where m is the slope of the line. There are infinite such lines depending on choice of m.